# QuickBlox Push notifications to the offline users issue

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, push, quickblox

I integrated QuickBlox in my iOS app. Chat works, however I have one problem:
There is description how to use automatically generated push notifications to offline users:
http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Push_notifications_to_the_offline_users

I implemented this feature and receive notifications. But if, for example, user of my app has two different dialogs: 1 - private, 2 - group; and chats in 1st dialog, somebody at the same time sends message in second dialog, then user doesn't get push notification.
Thus it seems to me that online status of user spreads to all it's dialogs when user logins to QuickBlox chat in app.
So I want to know is my assumption right? Can you please help me with this issue? Because in this situation I have to write my own logic for sending notifications to offline users.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you describe you problem in more detail with steps that you did?

And please look at the http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Alerts , by this link you may found your solution.